# C++ ifstream; every '\n' character is printed twice

Tags: c++, newline, ifstream

i've created a little program that implements operator[] to read files by indexing.
There's code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Findexer
{
    ifstream* f;
public:
    Findexer(string s)
    {
        f = new ifstream(s, ios_base::in);
        if (!f->is_open())
            cout << "Can't open file: " << s;
    }
    ~Findexer()
    {
        delete f;
    }

    char operator[](size_t ind)
    {
        f->seekg(ind);
        return f->get();
    }

};

int main()
{
    Findexer f("file.cpp"); //file with this program; it is the same with any other file
    for (int i = 0; f[i] != EOF; ++i)
        cout << f[i];
}
```

It works fine except that it prints every new line character twice.
There's beginning of output:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>



using namespace std;



class Findexer
```

I've no idea why it happens, could not google anything useful. :( Please help!

Comment: Are you on Windows? It looks like a mess up of the unfortuante `\r\n` line-termination on Windows.

Comment: @Angew: my thoughts too, I wonder if `cout << '\r'` could run afoul of stream eol conversion and be interpreted as `\r\n`.

Comment: @Angew Yes i am. but i thought there're '\n' characters hidden at the end of every text file lines, not '\r'

Comment: @Kirill Unix uses `\n` for line termination. Old MacOS uses `\r` for line termination. Windows uses the character-pair `\r\n`, and there's complex handling of converting this to `\n` and back in text-based I/O. Just read up all the docs on what the functions do, and/or work in binary mode.

Comment: Technically [`std::istream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) without arguments doesn't return `EOF`. It returns a value comparable to [`std::char_traits::eof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/eof).

Comment: As for your problem, have you tried printing the values of the characters you read? Then you will see exactly what you read.

Comment: @Angew, i've tried f = new ifstream(s, ios_base::in | ios_base::binary); and now it works w/o any other changes. that's curiously.. thank you and others

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, it prints 10 twice. i mean at the end of line ;)

Comment: if i use text mode ofcourse. and if i use binary its 13 and 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are running it in windows and you use MSVS?

Most likely it's a problem with DOS/UNIX encoding of newlines.
Check in the editor that shows control characters how exactly newlines are encoded in file.cpp. On linux system your code runs fine and prints the file correctly.

Comment: yes i am on windows but i use codeblocks. i will try checking it but it will take time because editor is quite big :) wrote it because i  dont want you to think that i've gone

Comment: well i've understood where was the problem. i will accept ur answer since Angew was writing in comments. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not related to the newline issue, but the test `f[i] != EOF` is incorrect.  `f[i]` returns a `char`, but `EOF` is an `int` that may either be out of the range of `char`, or have the same value as a genuine character.

In fact, if you want to unambiguously distinguish EOF from valid chars, `EOF` *must* be outside the range of the value returned by the stream read operation.

The way you have done it: if plain `char` is unsigned and `EOF` is `-1` then the test for EOF will never succeed. Or if plain `char` is signed and `EOF` is `-1`, then it will match EOF for the valid char `-1` (which is represented by `0x80`).

Also, as Joachim Pileborg points out, `EOF` may not even match `std::char_traits:eof` (although sane implementations are likely to use the same value for both).

This problem occurs in C also, when people try to compare the return value of `getchar()` to `EOF`.  C solves this by having `getchar()` return an `int` in the range `0-255` (assuming you use 8-bit chars) even if plain `char` is signed; and `EOF` is usually `-1`.

To fix your code you may want to consider something similar, or perhaps just revert to having a function instead of an overloaded operator, that "returns" the char by reference, and uses its actual return value to indicate success or failure, just like `std::istream::get(char&)`.

NB. your use of `new` and `delete` is unnecessary, just make `ifstream f` be a member of your class.

Comment: i am from now on will user char_traits<T>::eof() instead of EOF. i have learned C first so have some problems with c++ :) i can't agree with some of your statements. "if plain char is unsigned and EOF is -1 then the test for EOF will never succeed" - is not it gonna treat -1 as maximal unsigned char?

Comment: and "NB. your use of new and delete is unnecessary, just make ifstream f be a member of your class" - not sure if i understood ur meaning. but if i can not use ifstream as member because i can't copy or construct ifstream with other ifstream. i also could not use references, because of error "error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::ifstream& {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>&}' from an rvalue of type 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}' "

Comment: No, if you compare a char to an int, then the char is promoted to int. So you check if (int)255 == (int)-1 , which is false.

Comment: `std::ifstream` can be copied and constructed from other ifstreams. Also they can be closed and reopened on a new file, if you need to do that.  Based on that error message it sounds like you put an `ifstream&` in your class, not an `ifstream` .

Comment: you are right about Uchar/int. thank you for being so helpful :) i still dont understand about ifstreams. probably im missing something, but i dont see [**here**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) copy constructor (which is deleted) or ifstream(ifstream) constructor. There's ifstream(ifstream&&) but im embarrased to say that i know nearly nothing about that kind of c++11 stuff yet :(